# How can I parallel execute sql for MySQL partition table each partition

Tags: mysql, partition

There is a partition table A, has 4 partitions, I want to load data to Table B.

```
insert into B select * from A partion (p0) where type = 0;
insert into B select * from A partion (p1) where type = 0;
insert into B select * from A partion (p2) where type = 0;
insert into B select * from A partion (p3) where type = 0;
```

How can I load data for each partition in parallel. just in one connection.

Comment: well you can't.

Comment: And besides what's the whole point of creating another table which is an exact copy of an existing table?

Comment: sorry, I forget the condition

Comment: that's still a pointless task

Comment: I have got the way, using mysql event, execute in parallel

Answer (score 0):

Try Apache Spark.

[Great Documentation at this link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/sql-programming-guide.html)

> These options must all be specified if any of them is specified. They describe how to partition the table when reading in parallel from multiple workers. **partitionColumn** must be a numeric column from the table in question. Notice that **lowerBound** and **upperBound** are just used to decide the partition stride, not for filtering the rows in table. So all rows in the table will be partitioned and returned. This option applies only to reading.